# Visual studio break continues upon reaching Application.Run()

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

i might be missing something important, but I am trying to debug a C# application following the code line by line through breakpoints and 'step-into' / 'step-over' but when I hit the line "Application.Run(new dialog)", my program quits from the break mode and continues to run. I am trying to figure out what is happening under the hood, but the application stops from the break mode. I am really new to visual studio and C#. any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Please post the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling Application.Run starts a new application message loop, and makes your dialog visible.

Your application is now waiting for messages from that dialog.

You can't get anything useful from trying to step into Application.Run. You don't have control over that code.

If you put a breakpoint on any event handlers in your dialog class, you should be able to continue debugging that way.

Comment: Actually you could put the breakpoint on the Forms constructor.

Comment: Yes, that would be the earliest next place you could hook in, but that executes before Application.Run - so I would have thought a step-in on the Application.Run line would take you into there first before it disappeared into the depths of Application.Run

Answer (score -2):

I am not familiar with C# or your ide but could it be that you hit run and not debug?

Comment: This would have been better as a comment, if you had the rep for that.